# How can I remove the white space between a header and a slider in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, header, slider, removing-whitespace

New to wordpress, I am trying to remove the white space between the header and the slider. Basically when I am trying to edit a wordpress page, every time there is an "add title" thing on top of page which I think is the reason for that happening.

This is a picture of the result:

[image]

And the wordpress dashboard:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to put the slider exactly below the header.

Like this :

[image]

I am using the Astra Theme and the plugins "mystickymenu" to make my header sticky and the "smart slider" to make the slider.

I have tried installing different themes and tried lots of different plugins, nothing seems to work to remove the "add title thing" completely. Even the disable button from Astra will not remove the feature.

I have also tried additional css to Astra, every new thing I insert to the page starts from the top of the slider, leaving always this white space between the header and the slider.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried that?
https://wpastra.com/docs/disable-title-from-pages-2/

Comment: I did!!It just makes it transparent!!

Comment: Is it local or online ? please show tools to check class, you migth just need to add a margin or display none. Is it the title block that is creating that ?

Comment: It is local. Unfortunatelly, I have no idea, I assume it is the title block, because everytime I add something or change it always starts below the white space. Like the slider. Where do I add the margin or display none?

Comment: Did you try to delete the title block from your page or specify you dont want to add a title ?
Ok please show us the what does it show when you inspect on your browser with right click

Comment: Eventually it was the title block. I eventually changed the css and installed wpbakery. I also found this article for everyone having the same issue. 
https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/hide-page-title-wordpress/
Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the page from pages you have to check "Deactivate title". It will exclude that code in the specific page.